# Glob is different value error opening a file and reading

Tags: linux, perl, recursion, glob

```
sub open_files {

    my @files = @_;
    my @lines;

    foreach (@files){
        print "$_\[1\]\n";
    }

    foreach my $f (@files){
        print "$f\[2\]\n";
        open(my $fh,'<',$f) or die " '$f' $!";
            print "$fh\[3\]\n";
        push(@lines,<$fh>);
        close($fh);
    }

    return @lines;
}
```

Hi i am having problems with opening files whose absolute path are stored in an array.

What i want to do is go through the array and open each file and then store their data inside `@lines` array and then close the file handle.

However i am able to open the `.html` files which are stored in the first child directory `.e.g /a/abc.html or /b/bcd.html` however it is not opening (or parsing ) the files which are in sub-child directories such as `/a/aa/abc.html or /b/bb/bcd.html`

I have put in some extra `print statements` in my script and numbered their output for the different print lines e.g. `[1] [2] [3]`.

This is the result of executing the above code:

The full code is :  [pastebin Full code](http://pastebin.com/DFsU1RUZ)

```
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/a/aa/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[1]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/a/aa/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
GLOB(0x898ad20)[3]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/b/bb/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[1]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/b/bb/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
GLOB(0x898ae40)[3]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/a/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[1]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/b/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[1]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/c/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[1]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/a/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
GLOB(0x898ae40)[3]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/b/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
GLOB(0x898ae40)[3]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/c/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
GLOB(0x898ae40)[3]
```

If you guys need the full code here it is :  [pastebin Full code](http://pastebin.com/DFsU1RUZ)

Comment: Err, I don't get your problem. What output was expected? It should be working all right. You can see that there won't ever be a difference between `[1]` and `[2]`?

Comment: It is not extracting the data from these files

`
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/a/aa/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
/mnt/hgfs/PERL/assignment/test/b/bb/1 - Copy - Copy (2).htm[2]
`

Answer (score 2):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: $0 (abs path to dir) " if @ARGV != 1;

my $dir = shift @ARGV;
our @html_files = (); 

file_find($dir);
print "html files: @html_files\n";

sub file_find {
    my $dir = shift;

    opendir my $dh, $dir or warn "$dir: $!";
    my @files = grep { $_ !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir $dh;
    closedir $dh;

    for my $file ( @files ) { 
        my $path = "$dir/$file";

        push @html_files, $file if $file =~ /\.html$/;
        file_find($path) if -d $path;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. maybe the error is due to my recursion part.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) does not recurse into sub-directories.

Instead, use [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use File::Find 'find';

my @files;
find( sub { push @files, $File::Find::name if /\.html?$/ }, 'base_dir' );

say for @files;
```

Comment: Well i am doing this for a polytechnic project and the assignment requires me to only `use Cwd();` and no other methods so i have to do manual recursion to get all child directories and then files in them and then parse them and collect data e.g. email address from the html files

Comment: Well.. don't expect me to do your homework for you. Let me refer you to Mark Jason Dominus' excellent chapter on recursion in [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) instead.

Comment: No please dont get me wrong i am trying my best my self but due to my a lack of understanding of perl even a small error can cause me a setback so i am just putting my qn here so that you guys can point me any small errors i am making.

Comment: That is fine. However, you didn't post the recursing part of your code, so one would assume you don't have it.

Comment: oh i linked it maybe you missed it my whole code is linked to pastebin below the box containing the errors thanks

Comment: Please post it here then. I, for one, cannot access it through pastebin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29673/discussion-between-deepaktivari-and-zaid)